# What is the correct and safe way to assign one table to another

Tags: php, sql

There is two tables, workers and jobs. Absolutely anyone can create job. When new job is created there is no worker assigned to it. But when any worker takes a job then the job's worker_id sets id of the worker

Now it end up with this structure

```
workers
id

jobs
id
worker_id int default -1
```

By default, any job has a worker_id -1, but when the worker take a job then worker_id sets the worker's ID.

**UPD.** I know about foreign key. But the question is that what default value I must use. Or maybe in this situation there is better way that I don't know.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, but it seems that you're simply looking for a foreign key.

Comment: Am trying to understand your question. Do you mean to ask how to make sure that only  id (workers) in 'workers' table are assigned to worker_id in jobs table?

Comment: If that was your question then as @Simon suggests it should be a foreign key.

Comment: This is called a foreign key. It's the standard way to have one table refer to another. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @Valli I know about foreign key. But the question is that what default value I must use. Or maybe in this situation there is better way that I don't know.

Comment: You can use whatever default value you want, but `NULL` would be the logical choice.

Comment: Like @AlexHowansky says Null will be meaningful.. If you wnat to have integer then make it 0 by default

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an intermediary table to hold information about the worker/job relation

```
jobAssignment:
 - job_id
 - worker_id
 - PK(job_id, worker_id)
```

To assign a worker to a job just insert a row into this table with the corresponding ids, to unassign just remove the row.